# Issue with intermediate certificate while configuring SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have trouble installing the ssl certificate in a server.
The vhost file looks like this

```
`<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile  /path/to/YourIntermediateCertificate.crt
  </VirtualHost>`
```

I have tried SSL checker and the results are as follwing.

[image]

the error it shows is

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
> install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
> certificate. [Learn more about this error](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html). The fastest way to fix this
> problem is to contact your SSL provider.

An intermediate certificate is already installed. The common name for server in the image should be same as host name. I am not sure why it is "CloudFlare Origin Certificate". Need help in solving this issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have researched and found an answer for this issue.

To resolve the issue we need to enable the proxy for all A, AAAA, and CNAME records using cloudflare dashboard. Below is the explanation for why to enable the proxy.

Normally, the request hit the origin(server) directly and response is served. To encrypt this communication we use SSL certificate. But, the SSL certificate is also used for the identity of the origin server. Here in the above case, no chain certificate file is provided to identify the origin server i.e yourdomain.com,  rather the certificate is issued to cloudflare.

After enabling the proxy, the request hits cloudflare and the same request is sent to the origin server, the response from origin server is received by the cloudflare proxy and it is sent to the user. In this way the users browser thinks cloudflare proxy as the origin server and identifies cloudflare since it has its own ssl ( we don't need to bother ).

After enabling proxy, we don't need any chain certificate file to be installed in the origin server. We just need to install the server certificate issued by cloudflare.